# save image path in cart session in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to store product image path in session for that i'm using following code :

```
 $product = $this->productRepository->findProductById($request->input('productId'));
    $options = $request->except($request->input('_token'), $request->input('productId'),$request->input('productPrice'), $request->input('quantity'),$product->images[0]['full']);
    Cart::add(array('id'=>uniqid(), 'name'=>$product->name, 'price'=>$request->input('productPrice'),  'quantity'=>$request->input('quantity'),'image'=>$product->images[0]['full'], 'attributes'=>array($options)));
```

> Product model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
}
```

> dd($product->images[0]['full']);

i'm getting

> "products/aF6RVb39xPDdF1jdTcpBTQKed.jpg"

here images is relation

other details are being stored in cart but image path is not getting stored.

Comment: You should move the image in a folder and then take the image path to store

Comment: I have image path in this variable :$product->images[0]['full']

Comment: What path return from this $product->images[0]['full']  try to find out first using dd($product->images[0]['full'] )

Comment: It is returning path like product/img_001.jpg but when i store it in cart session with key image it did'nt get stored

Comment: What will return from $product, give me the screen shoot of dd($product)

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: Now it’s work ?

Comment: my issue is this path is not saving in cart session i want to show product image in my shopping cart page

Comment: my issue is this path is not saving in cart session i want to show product image in my shopping cart page

Comment: When you access image from session what you get ? Null or empty ?

Comment: when i run following code @foreach(\Cart::getContent() as $item) {{  $item->image }} nothing gets printed on view

Comment: <?php dd(\Cart::getContent()) ?> what will print let me know

Comment: Darryldecode\Cart\CartCollection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [5e529971801f0] => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemCollection Object ( [config:protected] => Array ( [format_numbers] => [decimals] => 0 [dec_point] => . [thousands_sep] => , [storage] => [events] => ) [items:protected] => Array ( [id] => 5e529971801f0 [name] => Indo Era [price] => 900 [quantity] => 1 [attributes] => Darryldecode\Cart\ItemAttributeCollection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [size] => medium [image] => ) ) [conditions] => Array ( ) ) ) ) )

Comment: Have you got your problem ? Try to add like this 
Cart::add(‘product’=>array(
‘id’      => your_id, 
‘name’ => your_product_name, 
‘image’ => your_product_image)
);

Comment: tried but it is not working syntax error

Comment: Knock me WhatsApp 01726903951